# GoogleAnalytics関係のAPIの違いについて

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, google-analytics

GoogleAppsScriptにて
Google Analytics API v3を使用しています。
Analytics Reportingへのv4に移行を推奨されているので、
移行する予定ですが、

そもそも、
Google Analytics API、
Analytics Reporting APIの違いが分かりません。
Google Analytics API v3というものはv4はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちわ、はじめまして

Google Analytics APIはGoogle Analyticsで利用する全てのAPIを指します。(Embed API,Management APIなど7つのAPIが含まれています)。
この中から、Core Reporting APIは分離され、Analytics Reporting APIv4となりました。その他のAPIはv3を継続して利用することができます。

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4#sticking_with_v3_or_earlier_versions_of_the_api